# Automatic page numbering

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a program that opens a word document and fills it with data.In the footer there is some data, but i also want the page count in the footer Which updates after you create a new page.I know this is possible with field code, but I don't know how to put in field code in word form C#.

I would like to use something like:

```
Phone: 00000000 mail: somemail@mail  Page {PAGE} of {NUMPAGE}.
```

**code for the footer**:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range footer = section.Footers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
footer.Text = ad.contactinfo(path, gud);
```

Is there a way to put field code in the document or is there anyother solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it :D

```
doc.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSeekView.wdSeekCurrentPageFooter;
Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText("some text \t Page ");
Object TotalPages = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldNumPages;
Object CurrentPage = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage;
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Fields.Add(doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, ref CurrentPage, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.TypeText(" of ");
doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Fields.Add(doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Range, ref TotalPages, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
```

Was hopping for a little bit less code but it works!

Answer (score 0):

One option is creating macro's in word and in C# you can execute your macro. In my opinion this seems the easiest way, since you can create as many macros as you want. When it works you only have to bother making macros and don't have to edit your code. Look at this page for more info about how this works: [How To Create an Excel Macro by Using Automation from Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303872). It is an article for Excell though, but the principle should be the same.

Comment: will it cause a problem when I install the program on other computers(because the macro is in word and not in the program)?

Comment: Probably, yes. Since macro's should be enabled first.

Comment: This would create an unnecessary dependency for the word templates to match, as every word template that should be used with the C# app would have to contain the correct macro(s) that are referenced in the C# code.